# How to connect to apple watch with HID keyboard?

Tags: apple-watch, hid

I have a HID keyboard based on nrf51,i looking for a way to connect it to my apple watch. 
How can i connect it to my apple watch?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a HID keyboard?

Comment: HW Keyboard over BLE

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect a keyboard to your watch.